# How to export headers from private Cocoa framework?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

There is a framework at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework
```

and I was wondering if it's possible to get the header information somehow?

It's a framework that theoretically allows to create plugins for XCode.

The header looks like this

[image]

and I can't access the headers as usual with public frameworks. But there has to be a way, because I found some resources online that list the classes, but the class descriptions are not available anymore: https://github.com/phausler/XcodeAPI/blob/gh-pages/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) utility to extract all Objective-C classes alongside with ivar and methods information.